# HAL SCCB Commuincation via I2C: HAL_ERROR Status

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

I am using an STM32f4 Discovery board to interface with an OV2640 Camera.  When attempting to set the SCCB registers, I am using I2C.  However, when doing a simple test I cannot connect to the device. I have connected the VCC, GND, SCL, and SDA ports to the STM32 and the camera.  I am using the following code to check if I am able to connect to the device.

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

 hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
 hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 10000;
 hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
 hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
 hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
 hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
 hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
 hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
 hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
 if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }
 }

void OV2640_IsReady(void)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

  status = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 0x60, 5, 1000);

    if(status != HAL_OK)
  {
      Blink_Orange();
  }
    if(status == HAL_ERROR)
  {
      Blink_Green();
  }
}
```

Each time I run this, the orange and green LEDs blink, indicating that I am receiving a HAL_ERROR when the controller checks the I2C device.  The slave read address listed on the datasheet is 0x60. I have tried modifying this address by attaching the R/W bit at the end (hex address changes to 0xC0) but this did not work.  As I understand, it should be very simple to connect to the SCCB interface as long as I have connected VCC, GND, SCL, and SDA.

What could be the problem with this connection?

Comment: I think the STM32 HAL uses 8-bit I2C addressing. But 0x60 << 1 = 0xC0 which you already tried. Are you sure you setup I2C correct, that you use the correct pins and you have appropriate pullups and not too long wires? Can you test to connect some other I2C device instead?

Comment: I tried a real time clock I had lying around, which interfaced fine.  It looks like this is an issue with SCCB vs I2C.

Comment: I'm out of obvious ideas. Maybe try replacing the Discovery board by a Raspberry Pi and do an I2C portscan. Or look for clues with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Did you also connect RST and PWDN? Is this a module? What are your pullup values?